# When a custom button is pressed UILabel won't update (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton, uilabel

(I'm currently learning iOS Development so I apologize in advanced of my limited knowledge.)

What I am trying to accomplish is that whenever you press either the addition or subtraction button the label will increment by one and will display the result by the label. I am having difficulty with displaying the result in the label.

This is my ViewController.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "StepperView.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
    UILabel *valueLabel;
}

@end
```

This is my ViewController.m file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "StepperView.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    int w;

    w = 0;
    [super viewDidLoad];

    StepperView *stepperView = [[StepperView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 50)];

    stepperView.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:stepperView];

    //    AddButton
    UIButton *additionButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(195, 318, 100, 100)];
    additionButton.frame = CGRectMake(stepperView.frame.size.width/2 + 50, stepperView.frame.size.height/2 - 25, 100, 50);
    [self.view addSubview:additionButton];

    //    Subtraction button
    UIButton *subtractionButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(195, 318, 100, 100)];
    subtractionButton.frame = CGRectMake(stepperView.frame.size.width/2 - 150, stepperView.frame.size.height/2 - 25, 100, 50);
    [self.view addSubview:subtractionButton];

    //    Label
    valueLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(195, 318, 100, 100)];
    [valueLabel setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    [self.view addSubview:valueLabel];
}

@end
```

This is my Delegate and Protocol:

StepperView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol SwitchViewDelegate

- (void)switchViewValueChanged:(int)number;

@end

@interface StepperView : UIView
{


}

@property (nonatomic,weak) id<SwitchViewDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

This is my StepperView.m file

```
#import "StepperView.h"

@implementation StepperView

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    [self setup];
    return self;
}

- (void)setup {
    UIView *stepperView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    stepperView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 40);

    stepperView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:21/255.0 green:101/255.0 blue:192/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    [self addSubview:stepperView];

    //    Add Button
    UIButton *rightView = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    rightView.frame = CGRectMake(stepperView.frame.size.width/2 + 50, stepperView.frame.size.height/2 - 20, 100, 40);

    rightView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:33/255.0 green:150/255.0 blue:243/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    [rightView setTitle:@"+" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [rightView addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self addSubview:rightView];        

    //    Subtract Button
    UIButton *leftView = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    leftView.frame = CGRectMake(stepperView.frame.size.width/2 - 150, stepperView.frame.size.height/2 - 20, 100, 40);

    leftView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:33/255.0 green:150/255.0 blue:243/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    [leftView setTitle:@"-" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [leftView addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self addSubview:leftView];        

    //    Label

 UILabel *valueLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(stepperView.frame.size.width/2, stepperView.frame.size.height/2, 100, 100)];

    [valueLabel setText:@"10"];
    [valueLabel setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [self addSubview:valueLabel];        
}

- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender{        
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *) sender;

    NSString *title = button.titleLabel.text;
    if([title isEqualToString:@"-"]) {                        
        NSLog(@"MINUS");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"PLUS");
    }

    //    NSLog(@"%@",title);
   }

@end
```

Comment: I don't see code related to updating the valueLabel text.

Comment: I see two "valueLabel". I'm not sure which one should really change. You didn't set the delegate of the `StepperView` object, and its delegate method `switchViewValueChanged:` is not called. There is not code when you set the text, only `NSLog()`

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you're trying you obtain as UI, i'm posting a possible solution which is using

1. The delegate to pass the information from `StepperView` to the `ViewController`
2. UILabel to present the result which is subview of `ViewController's` view, instead to be subview of `StepperView`

ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "StepperView.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
    @property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *valueLabel;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "StepperView.h"

@interface ViewController () <StepperViewDelegate>

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    StepperView *stepperView = [[StepperView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 50)];

    stepperView.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:stepperView];
    stepperView.delegate = self;

    //    Label
    self.valueLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(195, 318, 100, 100)];
    [self.valueLabel setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    [self.view addSubview:self.

valueLabel];
    }

#pragma mark - StepperViewDelegate

- (void)stepperView:(StepperView *)stepperView valueChanged:(NSInteger)value {

self.valueLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", value];
}
    @end
```

StepperView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class StepperView
@protocol StepperViewDelegate
  - (void)stepperView:(StepperView *)stepperView valueChanged:(NSInteger)value 
@end
@interface StepperView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<StepperViewDelegate> delegate;

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger stepperValue;
@end
```

StepperView.m

```
#import "StepperView.h"

@implementation StepperView

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    [self setup];
    return self;
}

- (void)setup {
    UIView *stepperView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    stepperView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 40);

    stepperView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:21/255.0 green:101/255.0 blue:192/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    [self addSubview:stepperView];

    //    Add Button
    UIButton *rightView = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    rightView.frame = CGRectMake(stepperView.frame.size.width/2 + 50, stepperView.frame.size.height/2 - 20, 100, 40);

    rightView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:33/255.0 green:150/255.0 blue:243/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    [rightView setTitle:@"+" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [rightView addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self addSubview:rightView];        

    //    Subtract Button
    UIButton *leftView = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    leftView.frame = CGRectMake(stepperView.frame.size.width/2 - 150, stepperView.frame.size.height/2 - 20, 100, 40);

    leftView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:33/255.0 green:150/255.0 blue:243/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    [leftView setTitle:@"-" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [leftView addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender{        
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *) sender;

    NSString *title = button.titleLabel.text;
    if([title isEqualToString:@"-"]) {                        
        self.stepperValue--;
    } else {
        self.stepperValue++;
    }

 [self.delegate stepperView:self valueChanged:self.stepperValue];
    //    NSLog(@"%@",title);
   }

@end
```

This should give you more clear vision how different components should corespondent with each other.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i understand clear what you want to do, but why don't you try to use the UIStepper button provided by iOS?
You can add an IBAction to your viewController and change the label with the value from the UIStepper.
Using swift:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var valueLabel: UILabel!
var currentValue = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func touchStepper(sender: UIStepper) {
    self.valueLabel.text = "\(sender.value)"
}
```

}